# WooCommerce & WooCommerce Shopee Intergration

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am a newbie in WooCommerce. Here the question:

After activate the WooCommerce plugin, do I need to fill in the store setup in order to use WooCommerce Shopee Intergration plugin (which I already activate)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set up your store in 5 steps
for details visit
https://www.buildthis.io/how-to/use-woocommerce-open-online-store-wordpress/

Comment: Thankyou Ejaz. Now I have 1 more question, can I set up the store using dummy data?